# Deleting an event from OSX Calendar with Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

Deleting an event from OSX Calendar with Applescript apparently fails - the event is removed from a database but still appears in the Calendar app.

Deleting the same event twice results in an error (event not found), so it is clear that the event, while still being visible in the app, is actually removed.

Example with a counting of the events so that one can see that it is indeed deleted even if it still appears in the app :

```
tell application "Calendar"
    tell calendar "Personnel"
        set myEventUID to uid of (make new event at end with properties {summary:"Name of my event", allday event:"true"})
        count events
        delete event id myEventUID
        count events
    end tell
end tell
```

The expected result is that an event is created in the Calendar app then deleted.
The actual result (in OS X Mojave 10.14.4, probably other versions as well) is that the event is created but not "fully" deleted : it still appears in Calendar app, even if you close and re-open the app or reload the calendars.
In Script Editor, the two counts of events included in this code sample are consistent : the second reports one even less, suggesting that it is indeed deleted (while you still see it in Calendar).

Answer (score 1):

What was missing in my code, and is probably very poorly documented, is that a calendar "responds to" the "save" command. The following code works as expeted:

```
tell application "Calendar"
tell calendar "Personnel"
    set myEventUID to uid of (make new event at end with properties {summary:"Name of my event", allday event:"true"})
    delete event id myEventUID
    save
end tell
end tell
```

... at the end you get no change as an event was created then deleted. But where it becomes odd (to me at least) is that when you **create** an event, you get it visible in the app and correctly recorded even *without* the "save" operation. When you **delete** it, you need to "*save*"... if anyone can explain a logic here, it is welcome! In any case, this solution apparently works, so I hope that it may help others.